# How to change URI's in a REST API?

Tags: php, rest, uri, api-design

I am coding a REST API with php. I want the URI to be *.../product/{id}* but to get returned a specific "product".
-I need to type in *..../product/read_one.php?product_id=7* - read_one is the php file

-I type the URIs in Postman.

How can I change it to *.../product/7*?

I am confused whether I can even use an .httaccess file or if I have to change up/create a new php file.
I haven't found any tips on the internet either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess to do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9])+$ ./product/read_one.php?product_id=$1
```

Basically when a request is made to a url that matches the left side regular expression, it's the same as going to the path on the right.

This specific regular expression checks for atleast 1 number after `product/`.